# How to draw dots on a line in tikz

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to draw a graph in tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, subfigure}
\usepackage[papersize={100mm, 100mm}, text={100mm, 100mm}]{geometry}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]


\newcommand{\order}[2][th]{\ensuremath{{#2}^{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin {figure}[1]
  \centering

  \subfigure[picture 1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]

\draw[xshift=-1cm] (0,0) coordinate[label=above:$a$](a) -- (1,0) coordinate [label=below:$u_1$](b);
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (2,0) coordinate[label=below:$v_1$](c) -- (3,0) coordinate [label=below:$u_2$](d);
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (4,0) coordinate[label=below:$v_2$](e) -- (5,0) coordinate [label=above:x](f);
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (5,0) coordinate[label=above:x] -- (6,0) coordinate [label=above:b](B);


\draw (b) to[out=110,in=70] ++(2,0);
\draw (c) to[out=110,in=70] ++(2,0);


   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But can't find how to draw dots on a, v1, v2 etc. Can you help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `node`s instead of coordinates like

```
node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$a$](a){}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{every node/.style={draw,shape=circle}}


\newcommand{\order}[2][th]{\ensuremath{{#2}^{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]

\draw[xshift=-1cm] (0,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$a$](a){} -- (1,0) 
node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$u_1$](b){};
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (2,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$v_1$](c) {} -- (3,0) 
node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$u_2$](d){};
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (4,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$v_2$](e){} -- (5,0) 
node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:x](f){};
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (5,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {} -- (6,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:b](B){};


\draw (b) to[out=110,in=70] ++(2,0);
\draw (c) to[out=110,in=70] ++(2,0);


   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to draw the circle separately like

```
\fill (a) circle[radius=1pt];
```

Do the same for other points also.

You have to correct these in your code though:

1. Don't use `\tikzstyle`. It is deprecated. Use `tikzset` instead.
2. Don't use `subfigure` (deprecated). Use `subcaption` (which gives `subfigure` environment) or `subfig` (which gives `subfloat`)
3. in the optional argument of `figure` environment, You have used `[1]` which is wrong. It has to be `[htbp]`.

Comment: Is it possible to draw similar graphics using the `graph` syntax? I can't (easily) get the node names to be displayed as labels instead of inside the nodes.

Comment: @Ragnar Please open a mew thread with your code with nodes. Also you may ask another new question for graphs syntax.